# Using Charles Proxy to debug Azure function locally

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-functions, charles-proxy

I'm creating an azure function to generate audio files from ssml. It worked great until a couple days back when I started getting empty file back from the API. If I use an app I created to request the conversion it work great, but when I use my azure function running locally on my mac, after a few files I start to get empty files (for the same file that work great with the app).

To debug the issue, i'd like to use Charles on my machine to see what the network request are and what is different between those two.

Unfortunately, when I try to run the function in VS code with Charles on, I get:

```
Core Tools Version:       3.0.3331 Commit hash: 0b57b1647c5a385beb8f7d64fa0e534ad4c7555d 
Function Runtime Version: 3.0.15371.0

[2021-03-08T05:24:12.902Z] A host error has occurred during startup operation 'd98e6aea-950a-4d9a-84db-afe74e83cabb'.
[2021-03-08T05:24:12.903Z] System.Net.Http: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. System.Private.CoreLib: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')
```

How can I configure the azure function tooling to work with Charles in VS Code?